# Example of writing Latitude Longitude to a Geofield?

Tags: location

I need to write a lat/lon value to a Geofield and I can't figure out how to set the field. I would prefer to do this using EntityMetadataWrapper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

And the answer:

```
    $entity_metadata_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node_object);

    $data = array(
       'lat' => 44,
       'lon' => -93
    );

    $entity_metadata_wrapper->field_position->set($data);
```

Comment: Although this is the accepted answer, I think 42droids ltd is the better one.

Answer (score 4):

Set Geofield using EntityMetadataWrapper if you only have the Longitude & Latitude information. (2015):

```
  $geofield_data = geofield_compute_values(array(
        'lat' => [Latitude], 
        'lon' => [Longitude]
  ), GEOFIELD_INPUT_LAT_LON);

  $entity_metadata_wrapper->field_position->set($geofield_data);
```

When a geofield is saved using the provided widgets, these values are passed
through the geofield_compute_values function in order to compute dependent
values. By default dependent values are computed based on WKT, but this may be
overriden to compute values based on other columns. For example,
geofield_compute_values may be called like so:

```
geofield_compute_values($values, GEOFIELD_INPUT_LAT_LON);
```

This will compute the wkt field (and all other fields) based on the lat/lon
columns, resulting in a point. As a developer this is important to remember if
you modify geofield information using node_load and node_save. Make sure to
run any modified geofield instances through geofield_compute_values in order
to make all columns consistent.

See docs (bottom) for more details:
http://cgit.drupalcode.org/geofield/plain/README.txt?id=7.x-1.x

Answer (score 1):

This can be done without entity_metadata_wrapper() as:

```
$node_object->position[LANGUAGE_NONE][0] = array(
  'input_format' => GEOFIELD_INPUT_LAT_LON,
  'geom' => array('lat' => 44, 'lon' => -93),
);
```

(I know you said "preferably with EntityMetadataWrapper", but I just thought I'd throw this in for reference.)